# Android Cursor in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I have problem as it follows:

```
try {
  long time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
  long time2, time3 = 0;
  mydb = openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
  Cursor select = mydb.rawQuery("SELECT DATE, PAYEE, CATEGORY, AMOUNT, _ID, "+
   "(select count(*) from TRANSACTIONS b where a._ID <= b._ID and ACCOUNT='4') as row "+
   "from TRANSACTIONS a "+ 
   "where row >= " + nRow + " and row <= " + (nRow+Integer.valueOf(9)) +
   " order by date desc, _id desc", null);

  time2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

  if (select.moveToFirst()) {
  do {
    // ...some code...
  } while (select.moveToNext());

Log.i("time","time query : "+(time2-time1));
Log.i("time","time move cursor : "+(time3-time2));
```

I want to show 10 by 10 records. When user scrolls to bottom then add 10 more in list.
The problem is time consumption for cursor. On the emulator time query returns 4, and time move cursor returns 264, which is excelent. But on real device (not the best one. CPU at 800MHz) time query takes 7 and cursor takes 1872 which is too slow. It is for 10 rows, but the truth is that table has over 1000 rows (and growing).

How to speed up cursor? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove the paging from your query. Instead, do a simple query without your `where` limits and just retrieve the amount of entries from the cursor you're currently interested in. (The better SQL way for such paging would be to use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` instead of `WHERE` like this.)
2. With the above change, you should probably do the counting in your code instead of SQL.
3. Add indexes to your `ORDER BY` columns such as `date`.
4. Measure again to see if there was a change for the better.

Comment: Excellent!!! Thank you very much. LIMIT helped!
Will add indexes also for future size of the table.